# how to save to utf8 in php

Tags: php

I wanna save chinese

if I don't have use utf8 to save it will be "?" ,so how to use utf8 to save.

or have other way can save chinese ,  make it not be "?".

thank help for everyone.

this it my php code (source code on internet)

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';



   // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: That is not enough. You should start with showing us how you send Chinese text.

Comment: have you tried `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);` ?

Comment: This PHP code is not about writing files, it's about getting data from a SQL database: you need to find out where your problem really is. Can you run code like `<?php $mydata = "我寫這在中國"; $fh = fopen("test.txt", "w"); fwrite($fh, $mydata); ?>` for instance (making sure PHP has [multibyte strings](https://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) enabled)? If so, filewriting is not your problem. Instead find out what you're putting into, and getting out of, your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you get your data from a form in browser you have to set the browser to utf8 like this :

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

and you have to set your database's table

```
collation to utf8
```

and your php connection to database to utf8

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 0):

before

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");
```

try

```
mysql_query("SET CHARSET utf8");
```